# Is it possible to inject a dependency "everywhere" automatically?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

This may seem like a stupid question but I got ask...

I have something like this:

```
APP.constant('MyGlobalConstants', {

});
```

Is there any way that I can inject `MyGlobalConstants` automatically in all controllers, services, factories so that I don't have to do it manually per controller/service/factory?

These constants are going to be used almost everywhere and it would be a way to avoid manually injecting it everywhere.

Is this possible somehow or should I just ignore the idea?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, have you been able to find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a [cross-cutting concern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern)

The best DI pattern for this is [the interceptor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/intercerception%20patt). You can use this for example with the [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) if you dont want every class to be intercepted.

I have used it for cross-cutting concerns like caching and logging, but I can see no reason why you cant do it for you constants class

Comment: That's really interesting. However, I have no idea how to implement this in AngularJS. I probably didn't make the right question...

Comment: Sorry - I didnt see the angular js reference. My answer was based on dependency injection principles only. I'd say your best bet would be to create a namespace in a js file and have it referenced in all of your pages.

Comment: That's not really the way with Angular.

Comment: @KerSplosh i want to use $log any place without write '$log' on injection, so how can i do that?